# Why does Rust's std::iter::zip seem to have interior mutability?

Tags: rust

As I understand, I shouldn't be able to have a mutable reference to an immutable piece of data. As such, if I want to create some `struct` that implements `Iterator` based on mutating an internal state, then I have to declare any instance of that `struct` as mutable in order to be able to create the mutable references needed.

To demonstrate, I constructed a simple example, below:

```rust
struct MyIter {
    internal_state: u32
}

impl MyIter {
    fn new() -> MyIter {
        MyIter{ internal_state: 0 }
    }
}

impl Iterator for MyIter {
    type Item = u32;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<u32> {
        self.internal_state += 1;
        Some(self.internal_state)
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    use std::iter::zip;

    #[test]
    fn mutable_declaration_no_zip() {
        let mut my_iter = MyIter::new();
        assert_eq!(my_iter.next(), Some(1));
        assert_eq!(my_iter.next(), Some(2));
        assert_eq!(my_iter.next(), Some(3));
    }
}
```

This compiles fine and passes, whereas if I change the test function to instead have an immutable declaration for `my_iter`, as below, then it refuses to compile with the expected message of `error[E0596]: cannot borrow 'my_iter' as mutable, as it is not declared as mutable`:

```rust
#[test]
fn immutable_declartaion_no_zip() {
    let my_iter = MyIter::new();
    assert_eq!(my_iter.next(), Some(1));
    assert_eq!(my_iter.next(), Some(2));
    assert_eq!(my_iter.next(), Some(3));
}
```

My question concerns the case where I do basically the same as above but use `std::iter::zip` to perform the iteration. What happens now is that even though I declare `my_iter` as immutable, the test compiles and passes, meaning that under the hood `zip` has mutated the state of the immutable variable that I passed it!

```rust
#[test]
fn immutable_declaration_zip() {
    let my_iter = MyIter::new();
    let nums: [u32;10] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
    for (i, num) in zip(my_iter, nums.iter()) {
        assert_eq!(i, *num);
    }
}
```

So, could someone please explain why `zip` was set up to be allowed to do this? How can `zip` call the `next()` method and hence generate mutable references to data that I have declared as immutable?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Mutability annotations (`mut` or lack thereof) follow the variable, not the value.

```
let mut my_iter = MyIter::new();
```

Here, it's not the *value* of `my_iter` that's mutable. It's `my_iter` itself. As long as `my_iter` owns that value, it's mutable. So you can call `my_iter.next()`, which requires a mutable reference.

```
let my_iter = MyIter::new();
```

Same argument but without the `mut`. As long as `my_iter` owns the iterator, it's *immutable*, so you aren't permitted to make a mutable reference to it.

*However,* the key phrase here is "As long as `my_iter` owns the iterator".

```
zip(my_iter, nums.iter())
```

The [signature](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/fn.zip.html) for `std::iter::zip` is

> ```
> pub fn zip<A, B>(
>     a: A,
>     b: B
> ) -> Zip<<A as IntoIterator>::IntoIter, <B as IntoIterator>::IntoIter>
> where
>     A: IntoIterator,
>     B: IntoIterator,
> ```

It takes both arguments by *value*. The moment you call `zip`, that function takes ownership of the value. That means that *nobody* currently has a reference (either mutable or immutable) to the value, and `zip` is free to decide if it's mutable or not, since it's now the exclusive owner.